# Import non-tabular txt or csv to R

Tags: r, import

I want to import a txt file into R. This txt file consists of various words separated by spaces and every line has a different arbitrary number of words, so that when I import it I get:

```
file<-read.table("paraules.txt",fileEncoding="latin1",header=F)

Error in read.table("paraules.txt", fileEncoding = "latin1", header = F) : 
  more columns than column names
```

How can I go about this? Is it possible to import a txt file with varying number of "columns" or should I edit my txt file to make it exportable?

Edit: the first lines of my txt file. As you can see, the number of words is different to each line, and there's no relationship within each column. Also, there are special characters:

```
fitxer,edició,format,visualització,ajuda,sense,títol,llibreta,aigua,llet,casa
finestra,taula,tecla,teclat,dit,ungla,nas,boca,orella,cap,altre,jugar,joc,jugador
canell,rellotge,teclejar,ordinador,mòbil,procedir,model,transformació,gràfic
```

Thank you

Comment: Try `readLines` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scan()` or `readLines()` should do.

```
h <- "fitxer,edició,format,visualització,ajuda,sense,títol,llibreta,aigua,llet,casa
finestra,taula,tecla,teclat,dit,ungla,nas,boca,orella,cap,altre,jugar,joc,jugador
canell,rellotge,teclejar,ordinador,mòbil,procedir,model,transformació,gràfic"
writeLines(h, "h.txt")
```

As you can see the ouput differs slightly, and `scan()` is most flexible in how it treats the data. Precisely how you do it depends on what you intend to use the data for later.

```
scan("h.txt", what="", sep="\n")
# Read 3 items
# [1] "fitxer,edició,format,visualització,ajuda,sense,títol,llibreta,aigua,llet,casa"    
# [2] "finestra,taula,tecla,teclat,dit,ungla,nas,boca,orella,cap,altre,jugar,joc,jugador"
# ...
# 
scan("h.txt", what="", sep=",")
# Read 34 items
#  [1] "fitxer"  "edició"    "format" "visualització" "ajuda"  "sense"        
#  [7] "títol"   "llibreta"  "aigua"  "llet"          "casa"   "finestra"     
# ...

readLines("h.txt")
# [1] "fitxer,edició,format,visualització,ajuda,sense,títol,llibreta,aigua,llet,casa"    
# [2] "finestra,taula,tecla,teclat,dit,ungla,nas,boca,orella,cap,altre,jugar,joc,jugador"
# ...
```